# Does iOS5 support datepicker html control?

Tags: iphone, html, ios, ipad, ios5

[this article](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/new-mobile-safari-stuff-in-ios5-position-fixed-overflow-scroll-new-input-type-support-web-workers-ecmascript-5) said yes. but I didn't succeeded to implement it.
Anybody has some examples about the html?
But on earlier version of iOS, how to implement the datepicker in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not datepicker implemented in HTML, that's a simple HTML Drop-down(SELECT) List with Day, Month, year Component Separately, but when this HTML is viewed in iPhone Web-view, or in browser, it is automatically converted in PICKER.